# Qt subclassed QStyledItemDelegate does not provide editing for columns

Tags: c++, qt, model

I sub-classed `QStyledItemDelegate` to provide editing for `QTableView`, my issue it looks likes the delegate is never called witch mean if double-click there is no editing behavior. Also, I checked the functions signature and they look correct.

**StudentNotesDelegate**

```
#include "studentnotesdelegate.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <qDebug>

StudentNotesDelegate::StudentNotesDelegate(QWidget *parent): QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}


QWidget *StudentNotesDelegate::createEditor(QWidget * parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const {
    if (index.column() > 3) {
        QLineEdit *inputText = new QLineEdit(parent);
        qDebug() << "ds:";
        inputText->setFrame(false);
        return inputText;
    }

    return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
}

void StudentNotesDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex & index) const {
    if (index.column() > 3) {
        QString indexValue = index.model()->data(index).toString();
        qDebug() << "Value:" << indexValue;
        QLineEdit *inputText = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
        inputText->setText(indexValue);
    }
}

void StudentNotesDelegate::setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index) const {
    if (index.column() > 3) {
        QLineEdit *inputText = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
        QString indexValue = inputText->text();
        model->setData(index, indexValue, Qt::EditRole);
    }
}

void StudentNotesDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget * editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const {
    if (index.column() > 3) {
        editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
    }
}


#ifndef STUDENTNOTESDELEGATE_H
#define STUDENTNOTESDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class StudentNotesDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    StudentNotesDelegate(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void    setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void    setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void    updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

#endif // STUDENTNOTESDELEGATE_H
```

This is how I call `setItemDelegate`:

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
    model->setQuery("Removed to avoid horizontal scroll");
    ui->listStudentsTable->setModel(model);
    model->insertColumns(3, classMaterials.length());
    StudentNotes::setModelHeader(model, classMaterials, classMaterials.length());
    //ui->listStudentsTable->setItemDelegate(new StudentNotesDelegate);
```

**UPDATE:**

I took of `QStyledItemDelegate` and instead sub-classed `QSqlQueryModel`, with reimplementation of `flags()`, `data()`, and `setData()`.

```
Qt::ItemFlags StudentNotesModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = QSqlQueryModel::flags(index);
    if (index.column() > 2)
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;

    return flags;
}

QVariant StudentNotesModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    return QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
}

bool StudentNotesModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, QVariant &value, int role)
{
    qDebug() << "setData() call";
    if (index.isValid() && index.column() > 2)
    {
        QAbstractItemModel *model = const_cast<QAbstractItemModel*>(index.model());
        model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

StudentNotesModel *model = new StudentNotesModel;Class.mat_class = " + mat_class;
    model->setQuery("SELECT Student.mat_stud, fname, lname FROM Student, Division, Class "
                    "WHERE Division.mat_div = Class.mat_class AND Student.mat_class = Class.mat_class" + studentsClassRoom);
    ui->listStudentsTable->setModel(model);
```

The `QTableView` is now editable but when I hit enter it resets back to the default value, I noticed that `setData()` is never called. what am I missing now?

Comment: In createEditor you use     return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index); when column is not 0,1,2,3 so try to call this default implementation of delegate in other methods too(setEditorData and so on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I advanced in my project, sub-classing `QSqlQueryModel` or `QSortFilterProxyModel` didn't feet my need, so I switched to `QStandardItemModel` because I need some rows and columns to be read only.

Set some columns to be read only:
    StudentNotesModel::StudentNotesModel(int rows, int columns, QObject *parent)
            : QStandardItemModel(rows, columns, parent)
    {
    }

```
Qt::ItemFlags StudentNotesModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = QStandardItemModel::flags(index);
    // Line 1,2, and 3 are read only
    if (index.column() < 3) {
        flags &= ~Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }

    if (index.row() > index.model()->rowCount()) {
        qDebug() << index.row();
        flags &= ~Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }

    return flags;
}

StudentNotesModel *model = new StudentNotesModel;
```

Set some rows to be read only:

```
for (int row = 0; row < numRows ; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < numColumns; ++col) {
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem("0");
        if (row == 7 || row == 8)) {
            item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
        }

        model->setItem(row, col, item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is `QSqlQueryModel`, it is read-only model. As doc said:

> The model is read-only by default. To make it read-write, you must
>   subclass it and reimplement setData() and flags(). Another option is
>   to use QSqlTableModel, which provides a read-write model based on a
>   single database table.

So editing delegate has no sense here. So try to use `QSqlTableModel` or subclass your current model.

Also in your current delegate try to call default implementation in every method as you did this in `createEditor()`.

But subclassing can be very long process, so try to use just `QSqlTableModel`. Suppose your code now is looking something like:

```
QSqlQueryModel *mmm = new QSqlQueryModel;
mmm->setQuery("SELECT * FROM newTab");
QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setItemDelegate(new ItemDelegate);
view->setModel(mmm);
view->show();
```

Then change it to:

```
QSqlTableModel *mmm = new QSqlTableModel(this,sdb);
mmm->setTable("newTab");
mmm->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
mmm->select();
QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setItemDelegate(new ItemDelegate);
view->setModel(mmm);
view->show();
```

And it is all what you need, item delegate is working now (I tested it on my computer, it works)

Comment: You suggest to subclass the current model, do you recommend to sub-class `QSqlQueryModel` and make it editable or `QAbstractItemModel`.

Comment: @HAßdøµ See my edit please, I tested it and it works, and I think that using QSqlTableModel can save your time(because QSqlQueryModel subclass can be long)

Comment: Unfortunately QSqlTableModel  is not suitable for my case since I am linking tow tables to fetch data, plus the data must not be committed immediately to database, rather then it waits until the user hit the save button.

Comment: @HAßdøµ Read in documentation what this line does: mmm->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit); it is not commited changes immediately

Comment: But it is still not suitable for my case since I am my query join multiple tables. Please have a look at my SQL query after I updated the question.